# What does "circumstantial consequence" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

How can of the phrase "circumstantial consequence" be explained? I vaguely understand the probable meaning, but it doesn't quite come into focus.
Is it something like (unintended) side effect?

Comment: Could you provide some context- perhaps the sentence in which you saw it?

Comment: My guess is that is means a consequence that derives, not from the crux of the matter at hand, but from circumstances that just happen to exist at the time. After having written that, I think that pretty much boils down to "unintentional consequences" as @tchrist has supposed.

Comment: @Jim it's from the "Echelon" lyrics by 30 Seconds to Mars, not much context there. It can be found in books though, for example "The thesis of an authoritarian and not totalitarian Fascism which became a dictatorship not by vocation, but merely as an unwanted circumstantial consequence..."

Comment: Ok, so I think @tchrist has it right.  It might also be phrased as an *unsought by-product*.  For example I might say that steam is a circumstantial consequence to boiling potatoes.  Steam is completely unsought but arises naturally when heating water to the temperature desirable for immersion cooking of potatoes.

Comment: "circumstantial consequence" is just a typo, or just very poor writing by someone who is not very literate (or perhaps, "arty-nonsense-like" writing, if you say it's from a song - like arty slightly-nonsensical Beatles lyrics, you know?)

they were thinking of "unintentional consequence" as tchrist explains.

it is very common on this site that non-native speakers, ask about some phrase they have seen (for example, "circumstantial consequence") which is, in fact, just an error by a poor writer, or a straight typo.

Comment: I'm not 100 percent sure the word "unintentional" can substitute for "circumstantial." If my worst enemy is murdered outside Al's Automotive, and I'm arrested for suspicion of murder, even though I was at Al's Automotive simply to get my car serviced, wouldn't my arrest be a circumstantial consequence of my being in the right place at the wrong time? In a court trial, some circumstantial evidence can be quite strong, and other evidence not so strong. My being accused of a crime could be attributed to a circumstantial consequence which is totally unrelated to the crime. Just a thought.

Comment: Lyrics often use words in nonstandard ways. It is futile to try to analyse such creative use of the language as if it were some precise technical terminology.

Answer (score 1):

From a social science / behavioral science point of view, it makes me think of "natural consequences."

For example:
I am choosing to take time to attempt to answer this question. Later, I may find that I do not have enough time to complete other tasks which then result in an undesirable outcome. This would be a natural consequence for not remaining focused on my pressing tasks. The existence of this post/answer is not so much the cause of the consequence, but me being distracted and spending longer meandering this website is the cause.

In Terms of circumstance, the cause of the consequence can be expanded even further. Such as, I have ADD (i.e., inattentive attention, easily distractible, interruptions or breaks in concentration) which add to the circumstances. Further, my dog is barking and needs some attention, let say that I provide my dog with attention, then I recive an important phone call that requires immediate action; this (or the circumstances) all take more time away from completing my tasks for the day and adds more time it takes me to be able to get back on task. If the circumstances were not present, I likely would have finished my tasks for the day and had a desirable outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the term 'circumstantial consequence' in a missive response to a  friend's woes as a defendant in an unfolding court case. My aim was to insinuate the principle of 'circumstantial evidence' without saying it outright, for I am not a person so qualified by learning or law to responsibly ascribe to any evidence that which in a court of law might fit the legal definition of circumstantial or otherwise.

On a personal note it seemed to me that based on the evidence I had, he was a victim of circumstance, finding himself in the wrong place at the right time of a police sting operation. My use of the term 'circumstantial consequence' might have been deftly served by 'unintended outcomes', but my nominal intent for creating a relation to the judicially significant term 'circumstantial evidence' would likely have been lost.

Comment: That might have been synonymous in that specific context, but 'unintended' cannot be equated with 'circumstantial'.